# Remove Exponential 'e' from the resultant number of multiplication program

Tags: flutter, dart

I was writing a simple string multiplication program.
Code for it is-

```
void main() {
String str1 = "175547878787788";
String str2 = "175547878787788";
int sum = 0, k = 1;
for( var i = str1.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
var val1 = num.tryParse(str1[i]) * k;

k *= 10;
var d = 1;
for(var j = str2.length - 1; j >=0; j--){
var val2 = num.tryParse(str2[j]) * d;
d *= 10;

sum += val1 * val2;

}
}
  print(sum);
}
```

When I am printing the resultant sum It is printing as follows

```
3.0817057746891913e+28
```

I want to print it as a big string removing e from the number.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you try this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.decimalPattern.html

Comment: It is throwing an error in DartLang. called "Undefined class NumberFormat". Any example of how to use it in Dart would be better. I am using dart online compiler. That compiler is popping this error

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the intl package. However, you said that you are using DartPad, I don't think you can import packages in DartPad.

Here's a Dart command line application that I just tried in my local machine:

pubspec.yaml

```
name: dartplay
description: A sample command-line application.

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.2.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  intl: ^0.15.8 #THIS IS THE LIBRARY 

dev_dependencies:
  pedantic: ^1.0.0
  test: ^1.0.0
```

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final bigNumber = 3.0817057746891913e+28;
  print(NumberFormat.compactLong().format(bigNumber));
  print(NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(bigNumber));
}
```

output

```
30800000000000000 trillion
30,817,057,746,891,914,240,000,000,000
```

I hope one of these work for you.